# Is there a way to use Google Adsense with cross origin isolation?

Tags: next.js, adsense, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

I am developing a website that uses depends on `SharedArrayBuffer`, to use `SharedArrayBuffer` your website needs to be cross origin isolated, which means your server response needs to contain the following headers:

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

I am using next.js and the headers seem to be working as I can check for cross origin isolation with the `crossOriginIsolated` global variable.

It seems like it is breaking Google Adsense as it is giving me these errors.

```
VM9:2747 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
show_ads_impl.js:101 GET https://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/osd.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep
VM48:2747 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
show_ads_impl.js:82 GET https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/sodar/sodar2.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep
show_ads_impl.js:82 Uncaught (in promise) undefined
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Ads have no plans to support cross-origin isolation. The recommendation is to register for an origin trial to temporarily exempt your domain to continue using SharedArrayBuffer without cross-origin isolation.

Good news is, the Chrome team is [working on a workaround for this issue](https://github.com/camillelamy/explainers/blob/master/anonymous_iframes.md) without this temporary exemption.

You can learn more about this matter here: https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/guides/cross-origin-embedder-policy

Comment: Are there any plans to add support for access-control-allow-origin: * so that Adsense could be loaded with Partytown https://partytown.builder.io/ ?